# "forge create" has been disabled in these command-line tools

Tags: trigger.io

```
D:\ti>forge create
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.34
[  ERROR] "forge create" has been disabled in these command-line tools

        App creation must now be performed through the Toolkit.

        https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit/

[  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn't expect:
[  ERROR] "forge create" is unsupported
[  ERROR] See D:\ti\forge-error.log for more details
[  ERROR] Please contact support@trigger.io
```

I use windows x64 with cywin and python installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to create an app through our Toolkit UI which you can download here: https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit

Once you have created an app via the UI you can build, run and package from the command-line. We do expect to support 'forge create' again from the command-line only soon but are making some major changes which need to happen first. I'll update again when this changes.

**UPDATE**: forge create is re-enabled through the command-line tools since the Toolkit 3.3.37 release.

Comment: How do I update from 3.3.34 to 3.3.37? I downloaded Toolkit after you updated this question is the old release still the default?

Comment: If you try to do a build with the Toolkit it will automatically trigger an update to itself.